# Weekly data for monthly adjustment in r

Tags: r

I am working on google search data sets and get the weekly data, from `2004.1.4 - 2018.10.28`. I want to make seasonal adjustment on monthly basis. But when I run following code in r:

```
GTI.data = ts(GTI.data, frequency=12, start=c(2004,1))

m <- seas(GTI.data)
```

It shows error: 
Error: X-13 has returned a non-zero exist status, which means that the current spec file cannot be processed for an unknown reason.

It seems that the error is caused by the frequency. Does anyone know what value should be the correct frequency? I searched previous questions but didn't find any answer. Thanks.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow; please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); also take a look at the [StackOverflow markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your question for readability

Answer (score 0):

When trying with the built-in dataset *EuStockMarkets*, you'll need to specify the end period as well:

```
library(seasonal)
GTI.data <- EuStockMarkets
GTI.data = ts(GTI.data, frequency=12, start=c(1991,1),end=c(1999,12))
m <- seas(GTI.data)
m
```

Comment: Thanks...but the code didn't seem working...it just acts like the "end" syntax didn't exist.

Comment: Fixed typo. When changing the end parameters, the output does change. When you use your data with end parameter, you still get the same error?